# Wpf TextBoxOutputter UI Task crash if to many ConsoleWriteLine from Background Task

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to build an Application that has a WPF UI and do some background tasks with file conversions. To show the operator the progress, I am using a TexBoxOutputter.

I have linked the console output to my TexBoxOutputter and linked the two Threads with a dispatcher. Now I can use the Console.Writeline command inside the background task so writes to the UI, which File I now try to convert.

This procedure in general is working well. But now the requirement is to convert an amount of about 500 files in one step. the background procedure is very fast, so this is used at about 30s for the whole 500 files. The issue is now, that if I write after each file the name of the file to the console, my UI thread stocks and is crashing and the whole procedure takes much longer. My guess is that the reason is that the Console.WriteLine overloads my UI thread.

So what do I need to change, if I want to have the same function to show on my UI which file is now converted but in a more stable and at least fast way?

Here are some code snippets:
TesxBoxOutputter:

```
public class TextBoxOutputter : TextWriter
    {
        volatile TextBox textBox = null;
        int count = 0;

        public  TextBoxOutputter(TextBox output)
        {
            textBox = output;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            UpdateTextBox(value.ToString());
 
        }

        private void UpdateTextBox(string text)
        {
            if (textBox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                textBox.AppendText(text);              
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    
                    textBox.AppendText(text);
                    count = count + 1;
                    //test Scroll down only after 30 lines added because otherwhise main UI thread will be locked.
                    if (count >= 30)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        textBox.ScrollToEnd();
                        
                    }
                    
                }));
            }
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
}
```

UI Console linkt to outputter:

```
           outputter = new TextBoxOutputter(ConsoleOutput);
            Console.SetOut(outputter);
```

Thread:

```
 
        void StartProcess(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
          
            if (SourcePath != null)
            {
                worker = new BackgroundWorker(); 
                worker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker2_DoWork);
            }           
            TheProgressbar.IsIndeterminate = true;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        private Thread _thread = null;


        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(StartConversion);
            _thread = new Thread(threadStart);
            _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
            _thread.Start();
        }
```

Comment: i need  a minimal sample to understant the logic...your piece of code doesnt show the link between your code and the wpf view

Comment: Surely this is a firehose bug and not a "crash".  Both BeginInvoke() and AppendText() are expensive methods, especially so when the textbox has a lot of existing text.  The reason why .NET has the StringBuilder method.  It isn't hard to get the main thread to burn 100% core, trying to keep up with the invoke requests.  It doesn't get around to its regular duties anymore, like rendering updates and responding to input.  Most basic thing you can do is using the BeginInvoke() overload that takes a DispatcherPriority argument, consider DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is the bad performance of the `TextBox`.
If you need input and output you must create a combined control that consist of a `ListBox` for the output and a `TextBox` for the input.
The advantage is that the `ListBox` provides UI virtualization.
Adding an item should be faster than manipulating a long multi-line string.
If you override the template of the `ListBoxItem` you will be able to remove the interaction behavior (like mouse over effects). It will make the `ListBox` appear like a `TextBox`.

The idea is to stack the `ListBox` on top of the `TextBox`. The result is a classic text console with a single line text input.
When the user presses enter you take the input and add it to the reversed (upside-down) `ListBox` and clear the `TextBox` afterwards. The result is that the send line moves up while the input line remains at the bottom. Like a classic console.

The following example shows such a simple text console. The `TextConsole` is able to send the input (scroll up) on Enter key press or via a `SendInputCommand` (routed command). It also allows to bind a source collection of strings to the `TextConsole.ConsoleOutputSource` property.
This enables you can update the console without sending explicit user input (for example to report progress).

**TextConsole.cs**

```cs
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TextInput", Type = typeof(TextBoxBase))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_OutputPresenter", Type = typeof(ItemsControl))]
public class TextConsole : Control
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> ConsoleOutputSource
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ConsoleOutputSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ConsoleOutputSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ConsoleOutputSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ConsoleOutputSource",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
    typeof(TextConsole),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<string>), OnConsoleOutputSourceChanged));

  private static void OnConsoleOutputSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => (d as TextConsole).OnConsoleOutputSourceChanged((ObservableCollection<string>)e.OldValue, (ObservableCollection<string>)e.NewValue);

  public static RoutedUICommand SendInputCommand { get; }
  private ItemsControl? PART_OutputPresenter { get; set; }
  private TextBox? PART_TextInput { get; set; }
  private ScrollViewer? OutputPresenterScrollViewer { get; set; }

  static TextConsole()
  {
    TextConsole.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextConsole), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextConsole)));
    TextConsole.SendInputCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Commit console input command", nameof(TextConsole.SendInputCommand), typeof(TextConsole));
  }

  public TextConsole()
  {
    this.ConsoleOutputSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    var sendInputKeyBinding = new KeyBinding(TextConsole.SendInputCommand, Key.Enter, ModifierKeys.None);
    _ = this.InputBindings.Add(sendInputKeyBinding);
    var sendInputCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(TextConsole.SendInputCommand, ExecuteSendInputCommand, CanExecuteSendInputCommand);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(sendInputCommandBinding);
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    this.PART_OutputPresenter = GetTemplateChild("PART_OutputPresenter") as ItemsControl;
    if (this.PART_OutputPresenter is not null)
    {
      this.PART_OutputPresenter.Loaded += OnItemsControlLoaded;
      this.PART_OutputPresenter.ItemsSource = this.ConsoleOutputSource;
    }

    this.PART_TextInput = GetTemplateChild("PART_TextInput") as TextBox;
    if (this.PART_TextInput is not null)
    {
      this.PART_TextInput.AcceptsReturn = false;
    }
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    _ = this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => _ = Keyboard.Focus(this.PART_TextInput));
  }

  private void OnItemsControlLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (TryFindVisualChildElement(this.PART_OutputPresenter, out Panel? itemsHost))
    {
      // Make items appear from bottom to top
      itemsHost.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    }

    if (TryFindVisualChildElement(this.PART_OutputPresenter, out ScrollViewer? scrollViewer))
    {
      this.OutputPresenterScrollViewer = scrollViewer;
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnConsoleOutputSourceChanged(ObservableCollection<string> oldValue, ObservableCollection<string> newValue)
  {
    if (this.PART_OutputPresenter is not null)
    {
      this.PART_OutputPresenter.ItemsSource = this.ConsoleOutputSource;
    }
  }

  private void CanExecuteSendInputCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.PART_TextInput?.Text);

  private void ExecuteSendInputCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.PART_TextInput is not null)
    {
      SendInput(this.PART_TextInput.Text);
      this.PART_TextInput.Clear();
    }
  }

  private void SendInput(string input)
  {
    this.ConsoleOutputSource?.Add(input);
    this.OutputPresenterScrollViewer?.ScrollToBottom();
  }

  private bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(DependencyObject parent, out TChild? resultElement)
    where TChild : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (parent is Popup popup)
    {
      parent = popup.Child;
      if (parent == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
    {
      DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

      if (childElement is TChild child)
      {
        resultElement = child;
        return true;
      }

      if (TryFindVisualChildElement(childElement, out resultElement))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextConsole}">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="Gray" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="Cursor"
          Value="IBeam" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextConsole}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListBox x:Name="PART_OutputPresenter"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     Focusable="False"
                     IsHitTestVisible="False">
              <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                  <Setter Property="Focusable"
                          Value="False" />
                  <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible"
                          Value="False" />
                  <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                      </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
                </Style>
              </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextInput"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     BorderThickness="0" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

In addition you must fix your threading code.
You should check if the API you use to convert the files exposes an asynchronous API that enables natural async/await for enhanced performance.
Such an API is preferred over multi threading.
The following code is a version of your original code modified to work with the `TextConsole` control.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <local:TextConsole Height="400"
                     ConsoleOutputSource="{Binding TextConsoleWriter.ConsoleOutputSource}" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public TextConsoleWriter TextConsoleWriter { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
    this.TextConsoleWriter = new TextConsoleWriter();
  }

  private void StartProcess(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.SourcePath == null)
    {
      return;
    }
      
    this.Progressbar.IsIndeterminate = true;

    // Create a background thread for the conversion job.
    // Note, that if you can use an async API to have asynchronous conversion,
    // you should prefer this over a background thread.
    // In case you need to do something once the conversion has completed (e.g. clean up),
    // simply await the Task.
    // If you don't await the Task you should consider to use a SemaphoreSlim
    // to restrict the number or concurrent operations (e.g., max two background thraeds).
    // If you only allow one operation, simply await the Task
    Task.Run(StartConversion);
  }

  private void StartConversion()
  {
    // Pseudo code
    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfosToConvert)
    {
      // Report the progress.
      // You can try different DispatcherPriority values to find which one
      // reliefs some pressure without deferring too much.
      // DispatcherPriority.Background is a good starting point.
      this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
        () => this.TextConsoleWriter.AppendLine(fileInfo.Name), 
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
  }
}
```

**TextConsoleWriter.cs**

```cs
ublic class TextConsoleWriter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> ConsoleOutputSource { get; }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

  public TextConsoleWriter()
  {
    this.ConsoleOutputSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  }

  public void AppendLine(string line)
  {
    this.ConsoleOutputSource.Add(line);
  }
}
```